# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1: i386: No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2, code-signing-entitlements

I have an error that just occurred. I think it was when I changed some of my build settings. I wanted my app to work with both armv6 and armv7. But now I get this error saying `Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1` and `i386: No such file or directory`. Here is the entire error log:

```
CodeSign /Users/Jacos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kapareskolan-asnymemcjzpjdwbpftlqeknpdmsq/ArchiveIntermediates/Kapareskolan/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Kapareskolan.app
cd "/Users/Jacos/Documents/Development/iOS/Official Apps/Kapareskolan 2.0"
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Distribution: Gun  Lindgren" --resource-rules=/Users/Jacos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kapareskolan-asnymemcjzpjdwbpftlqeknpdmsq/ArchiveIntermediates/Kapareskolan/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Kapareskolan.app/ResourceRules.plist i386 armv6 armv7 --entitlements /Users/Jacos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kapareskolan-asnymemcjzpjdwbpftlqeknpdmsq/ArchiveIntermediates/Kapareskolan/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kapareskolan.build/Release-iphoneos/Kapareskolan.build/Kapareskolan.xcent /Users/Jacos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kapareskolan-asnymemcjzpjdwbpftlqeknpdmsq/ArchiveIntermediates/Kapareskolan/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Kapareskolan.app

i386: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this problem and still have my app work with both armv6 and armv7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error looks like you have added things to the **Other Code Signing Flags** build setting somehow which should not be needed (it is empty by default). You should probably only need to change the **Architectures** build setting.

Note that iPhone 3GS and higher, iPod Touch 2 and higher and all iPads have armv7 ISA. So armv6 is only needed if you want to support iPhone 3G or lower and old iPod Touche devices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: Yes, I solved (before I saw this). But since this was the problem and you suggested it I will mark your answer as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is the case in ImageApp, an older Apple sample code project--clearing the flags fixed the signing error.