# facebook integration codesign error

Tags: xcode, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook to my app

1/ I tried the static library (for arc project) and had a message saying something like "the lib is not build for your current target (armv7". I read hundreds post and cant solve the pb.

2/Now I'm just dragDroping the src and put a flag -fno-objc-arc to all the added flag.

It still doesn't work!!!

Here is my error message :

```
CodeSign /Users/sylvainguilbert/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aviso_0.1-fhjiibqwcoohxmcueawtpqtjuknh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Aviso_0.1.app
cd /Users/sylvainguilbert/Documents/dev/Aviso_0.1
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 752c4685452b4d64922b21157564304b5db0e616 --resource-rules=/Users/sylvainguilbert/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aviso_0.1-fhjiibqwcoohxmcueawtpqtjuknh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Aviso_0.1.app/ResourceRules.plist armv7 armv6 --entitlements /Users/sylvainguilbert/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aviso_0.1-fhjiibqwcoohxmcueawtpqtjuknh/Build/Intermediates/Aviso_0.1.build/Debug-iphoneos/Aviso_0.1.build/Aviso_0.1.xcent /Users/sylvainguilbert/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aviso_0.1-fhjiibqwcoohxmcueawtpqtjuknh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Aviso_0.1.app
```

armv7: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

This is driving me crazy , what am I missing?

Comment: I found my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869607/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-i386-no-such-file-or-directo

I had had armv6 armv7 to my build settings when I removed them (both from my project and my target) Everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here : [Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1: i386: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869607/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-i386-no-such-file-or-directo)

I had armv6 armv7 to my build settings when I removed them (both from my project and my target) Everything was fine.